# Responsive Scrollable Div

Tags: css

I'd like to know if it's possible to make a div responsive and at the same time make its content scrollable within certain dimensions (max/min height).

Here is my attempt

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVEbWG

While the width is responsive the height remains the same (while I would like it to be 100px min and 400px max).

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
}
.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Simple**, just use the `vh` css unit for the height, like so: `height: 100vh`

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;

    border: 1px solid red;
}
.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The `1 vh` unit is relative to 1% of the height of the **viewport**, meaning that your div will be dependent on the height of your viewport.

If your viewport will be smaller than the div, you will be able to scroll trough it.

Comment: If you think I have answered your question, please close this thread by accepting the answer or wait for a better one.

Comment: `100vh` won't work for me. I'd like the container to be responsive only within certain dimensions - let's say between 100px (min) and 400px (max)

Comment: You should really be more accurate with the word "responsive" as no one here knows what you really want.

Comment: By responsive I mean that the container can't grow beyond 400px in height  but at the same time can't be smaller than 100px. Does that help?

Comment: Here is another example of what I have in mind: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdQqGq try to resize the window vertically and you'll see the container stays at 400px.

Comment: So, you want the following: minimum size of the div is: x, max size of the div is: y. So you want your div to be: **x < div > y** and be scrollable ("responsive")?

Check the updated link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdQqpj


Answer me if this is the thing you were looking for, because the div wont be smaller than 100px and wont be larger than 400px and is scrollable in the middle...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The `.wrapper` div is always 300px tall. Try resizing the window.

Comment: Yes of course it's allways 300px tall if you resize the window! I think you do not understand how things work in css. Thats why no one understands your request, because you can not make it any more "responsive", at least by how you describe it. Try reducing the content (the actual words in the content) and you will see what `min-height: 100px` does... 

Thats why I told you to use `vh` if you want your div to be "responsive".